# Is 64GB the max amount of memory for an Apple computer?

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I was looking at a comparison between 2017 Apple computer offerings and the highest end system appears to be the [Mac Pro, a tower-type computer 6 inches in diameter and 9 inches high](https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/). This system is described as expandable in memory up to 64 gigabytes. So, is that the top-end limit on memory for current Apple computers?

Answer (score 14):

Depends what you mean by "current". The discontinued [Xserve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xserve) range of Apple servers maxed out at 96GB (although Apple only claimed 48GB).

More currently, the answer continues to be **Yes and No**.

- Yes, Apple only will **support or sell 64 gig** of RAM on the MacPro and iMac.
- No, the MacPro newer than 5,1 and most newer 27 inch iMac will accept and run quality memory that add up to **128 GB reliably**.
- https://www.macmemory.com/

I would expect the next iMac Pro and Mac Pro to raise the ceiling for both the official limit and unnoficial limit.

Comment: Well done on the Xserve data - let’s have a combined answer that’s comprehensive?

Comment: Not current... but just to note the Mac Pro 5,1 would take 64GB in dual channel, or 96GB in triple.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.apple.com/imac-pro/
According to the specs here for the new (not yet released) iMac Pro, you can order it from Apple with up to 128 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

My 2010 12 core MacPro has 8 slots, and I can buy memory up to 16GB/slot. That's 128GB for this model. It's currently loaded with 96GB and running well. The 2013 cylinder has 4 slots but can use 32GB ram per, so same 128GB.